# Pre-Calculus definition Clarification

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The x-axis is a horizontal asymptote for the exponential function $f(x) = a^x$. This is because when $a>1$, we have $a^x \to 0$ as $x \to -\infty$, and when $0 < a < 1$, we have $a^x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

I don't understand this definition. Can someone explain it to me as if I am a 5 year old?

Answer (score 1):

try specific values for $a$ and graph the functions. I would first try $a=2$, then $a=1/2$ and then compare the 2 graphs.

http://www.drdelmath.com/college_algebra/image/exponential_bunch_graph.gif